# Mongodb average where value is not null

Tags: mongodb

I want to calculate the rating average with condition rating different 0 because the rating is by default 0 , This is what returns an incorrect rate

```
.aggregate([
            { $match : { id : sessionId }},
            {
              $group: {
                _id: null,
                countAverageRate: {
                  $avg: '$pupilRate'},
}]);
```

Comment: did you try using $match to filter out the documents that have 0 pupilRate?

Comment: What about adding a filter of `{$ne: null}` in `$match` stage ?

Comment: @Joe I need pupil with the rate 0 too, for count the users who did not rate

Answer (score 1):

The $average operator will give you the average of that field across all of the documents.

To get the partial average of filtered values, use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#cond-aggregation) to count and sum the desired values, and calculate the average separately.

```
.aggregate([
            { $match : { id : sessionId }},
            {$group: {
                _id: null,
                countAverageRate: {
                  $avg: '$pupilRate'},
                ratedCount: {$cond: {
                   if: {$gt:['$pupilRate', 0]},
                   then: '$pupilRate',
                   else: 0
                 }},
                ratedSum: {$sum: {
                   if: {$gt:['$pupilRate', 0]},
                   then: 1,
                   else: 0
                }} 
             },
           {$addFields: {
              ratedAverage: {$divide:['$ratedCount', '$ratedSum']}
           }}
]);
```